# "FETCH NEXT" in SQL into Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I have used a cursor and fetch function in SQL Server Stored Procedure

```
OPEN Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @RegionId
```

But how to do the same in Oracle Stored Procedure. Please Help

Answer (score 4):

Below is the example of how Cursor can be used in Oracle...

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR Cursor1 IS 
   ...Some sql  statement....

BEGIN
  OPEN Cursor1;
  LOOP
    FETCH Cursor1 INTO RegionId;
     EXIT WHEN Cursor1%NOTFOUND; 

    ......

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE Cursor1; 

END;
```

Comment: I want the next value not the current value

Comment: FETCH gets the *next* record in the cursor, so this is the solution does what you need.  Why don't you try it?